# C# abstract class calling base with generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

If I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Page<T> where T : class
{
    public Func<T, object> SortBy { get; private set; }

    public Page(Func<T, object> sortBy)
    {
        this.SortBy = sortBy;
    }
}
```

How can I call the base constructor from the inheriting class? I want to do something like this:

```
public class ProductGridPage : Page<ProductGrid>
{
    public ProductGridPage() : base<ProductGrid>(pg => pg.Title)
    { 

    }
}
```

However `base<ProductGrid>(pg => pg.Title)` is not valid and wont compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public abstract class Page<T> where T : class 
{ 
    public Func<T, object> SortBy { get; private set; } 

    public Page(Func<T, object> sortBy) 
    { 
        this.SortBy = sortBy; 
    } 
} 

public class ProductGridPage : Page<ProductGrid> 
{ 
    public ProductGridPage() : base(pg => pg.Title) 
    {  

    } 
}
public class ProductGrid
{
  public string Title;
}
```

Comment: Lol - so simple thanks - I thought I tried this but it I was changing things in both classes and may not have had the constructor correct in the base class, thanks for your help ;-)